# Draw line with DashPattern resutls a solid line in C#

Tags: c#, gdi+

I draw a line with [2/3f, 1/3f] dash pattern, but results a solid line.

I also tried other dash patterns, here is the results:

```
[2/3f, 1/3f]: a solid line
[0.5f, 0.25f]: a good dash line
[0.6f, 0.3f]: a good dash line
[0.66f, 0.33f]: a bad dash line
[2, 1]: a good dash line
```

```
using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(600, 600))
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
    {
        g.Clear(Color.White);
        
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);
        pen.DashPattern = new float[] { 2/3f, 1/3f};

        g.DrawLine(pen, 0, 300, 600, 300);
    }
    b.Save("test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

[image: test]

Comment: I cannot explain the results for your values, but I'd say the unit is pixels. For values > 1 the result looks as expected.

Comment: Based on [`Pen.DashPattern`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.pen.dashpattern) `new float { 2f, 1f }` should do it but you also discovered this. If the question is _why_, the answer lies somewhere deep in the wrapped GDI+ sources, which is not open source. You can try digging the [libgdiplus](https://github.com/mono/libgdiplus/blob/main/src/pen.c) or [ReactOS](https://doxygen.reactos.org/d0/de4/dll_2win32_2gdiplus_2pen_8c.html) sources but be aware that they are not necessarily 100% compatible. But why is it so important if you already have a good solution?

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg Actually, I have a pen with `width = 1/3f` and `dashPattern = new float[]{2, 1}`, this works OK in C#. However, when come to Java `BasicStroke(float width, int cap, int join, float miterlimit, float dash[], float dash_phase) `, the para ` float dash[]`  will be `new float[] { 2f * width, 1f * width}`, that is `dash = new float[] {2f/3, 1f/3}`, this will also result a solid line in Java. So I investigate it more.

Comment: As @KekuSemau said the unit is pixels. I think that rounding takes place, which results in a dash pattern of 1, 0 in your case (2/3f => 0.66 => 1 and 1/3f => 0.33 => 0) Therefore you see a solid line.